# Convert SQL date to Java.util.date

Tags: java, date, format, java.util.date

My requirement is to return the `dueDate` field as a date to the calling service.

The back end code returns the date in `mm/dd/yy`. When I map those fields to the Java code, my object contains the date field of type `java.sql.Date`.

The field that is defined in the object is (note it's the pseudo):

```
import java.sql.Date;

private Date dueDate;

/**
 * @return the dueDate
 */
public Date getDueDate() {
    return dueDate;
}

/**
 * @param DueDate the DueDate to set
 */
public void setDueDate(Date dueDate) {
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("DueDetails [dueAmount=").append(dueAmount).append(", dueDate=").append(dueDate)
            .append("]");       
    return builder.toString();
}
```

When I print the object, the `Date` field comes in this form:

```
dueDate=Thu Oct 25 20:00:00 EDT 2018
dueDate=Thu Aug 02 20:00:00 EDT 2018
```

When I query from backend, it shows me the proper format (mm/dd/yy), which I should return to the calling service.

Comment: Nono, i was wrong i set it as a possible duplicate wrongly , i retracted the flag but the comment persisted

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. Can you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please? Also asking because I think you may solve your own problem when you try to do that.

Answer (score 4):

check this

```
//converting java.util.Date to java.sql.Date in Java
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(now.getTime());
System.out.println("Converted value of java.sql.Date : " + sqlDate);

//converting java.sql.Date to java.util.Date back
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date(sqlDate.getTime());
System.out.println("Converted value of java.util.Date : " + utilDate);
```

from this link: http://www.java67.com/2012/12/how-to-convert-sql-date-to-util-date.html

Then you can use SimpleDateFormat to format the date as you like:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String strdate = simpleDateFormat.format(myJavaDate);
System.out.println(strdate);
```

Comment: when I use formatter it changes to String right. I want to retain it as a date field but with mm/dd/yy.

Comment: Date is an abstract representation of a date. The format only matters when that date must be printed, parsed or written to something.

Comment: the above changes you made results in String(the one printed too). But i want to format and send as Date. Not sure if im missing something here,

Comment: Send the date where? made results in String?

Answer (score 2):

## `java.util.Date` vs `java.sql.Date`

Your output looks to be coming from a `java.util.Date` rather than a `java.sql.Date`.

It is unfortunately easy to mixup the two. Besides the `Date` name, the `sql` one technically is a subclass of the other `util` one. Beware: This is a hack, and a bad hack at that. The documentation warns us to pretend the two are *not* in an inheritance relationship. But the compiler does not know that.

Here is some example code showing these two classes and the different behavior of their respective `toString` method.

```
// Legacy classes
System.out.println( "java.sql.Date: " + new java.sql.Date( Instant.now().toEpochMilli() ) ) ;
System.out.println( "java.util.Date: " + new java.util.Date() ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com.](https://ideone.com/TUtiS2)

> java.sql.Date: 2018-07-31
>
> java.util.Date: Tue Jul 31 22:44:14 GMT 2018

You can see the `java.sql.Date::toString` method uses the shorter YYYY-MM-DD format used in SQL environments. That format also happens to comply with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard as well, by the way.

In contrast, the output you report matches that of `java.util.Date::toString`.

## java.time

The issue is moot. You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

- `java.sql.Date` is replaced by `java.time.LocalDate`, a date-only only value without a time-of-day and without a time zone. (FYI, `java.sql.Date` pretends to have no time-of-day or time zone but actually has both, as an awkward subclass of `java.util.Date`.)
- `java.util.Date` is replaced by `java.time.Instant`. Both represent a moment in UTC, though `Instant` has a finer resolution of nanoseconds instead of milliseconds. (FYI, `java.util.Date` actually has a time zone buried deep, inaccessible without getter/setter methods, but used in `equals` etc. One of many poor design decisions in these legacy classes.)

Here is some code, counterparts to that seen above.

```
// Modern classes
System.out.println( "LocalDate.now(): " + LocalDate.now() ;
System.out.println( "Instant.now(): " + Instant.now() ) ;
System.out.println( "ZonedDateTime.now( … ): " + ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ) ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com.](https://ideone.com/TUtiS2)

> LocalDate.now(): 2018-07-31
>
> Instant.now(): 2018-07-31T22:57:27.763Z
>
> ZonedDateTime.now( … ): 2018-07-31T23:57:27.904+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).